# How to use a modal as a reply to a select menu command

Tags: discord, discord.js

Hi i have a slash command that reply with a select menu and i want to open a modal to the user when he select one of the options but i can't reply to an interaction twice so i wanted to know if there is a way to do it.

I tried to send the select menu as a normal message in the same channel but everytimes the command is used there will be an error message because in didn't reply directly to the commands. if there is a way to make this message not appear it could also work for my ussage.

please leave a message if you can help me thx.

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');
const { ActionRowBuilder, EmbedBuilder, StringSelectMenuBuilder, ModalBuilder, TextInputBuilder, TextInputStyle } = require('discord.js');

const matches = require("../../differents-matches");

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('matchdisponibilities')
    .setDescription('Used to give your disponibilities for a specific match'),

async execute(interaction, client) {

    const userRoles = interaction.member.roles.cache.map((role) => role.id)
    let allMatches = await matches.find()

    let userMatches = []

    allMatches.forEach(element => {
        userRoles.forEach(role => {
            if (element._team1 === role || element._team2 === role) {
                userMatches.push(element)
            }
        })
    })

    const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
    .setTitle('Select a match')
    .setColor(0x18e1ee)

    const componentsMenu = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(
            new StringSelectMenuBuilder()
            .setCustomId('select')
            .setPlaceholder('Nothing selected')               
        )

    userMatches.forEach(element => {
        componentsMenu.components[0].addOptions(
            {
                label: interaction.guild.roles.cache.get(element._team1).name + ' VS ' + interaction.guild.roles.cache.get(element._team2).name,
                value: element.id,
            }
        )
    })

    const modal = new ModalBuilder()
    .setCustomId('test')
    .setTitle('test2')

    const textInput = new TextInputBuilder()
    .setCustomId('test3')
    .setLabel('test4')
    .setRequired(true)
    .setStyle(TextInputStyle.Short)

    const channel = interaction.channel

    modal.addComponents(new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(textInput))

    const message = await interaction.reply({embeds: [embed], components: [componentsMenu], fetchReply: true})

    const collector = message.createMessageComponentCollector({
        filter: (u) => {
            if (u.user.id === interaction.user.id) return true
            else{
                return false
            }
        }            
    })

    

    collector.on('collect', async (cld) => {
        if(cld.values[0] === '63960e06ee2ff68635eff3bb'){
            await interaction.showModal(modal)
        }
    })
}
```

}

Comment: Mind providing code?

Comment: Added my code to the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that i was using `await interaction.showModal(modal)` in my colector for the select menu instead of `await cld.showModal(modal)` so i was responding to the interaction of the slash command instead of the interaction of the select menu